# How can I select from optional fields instead of using a required field?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to add a data source `data_source_person` that supports 2 methods of input:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
    "id": {
        Type: schema.TypeString,
        Computed:    true,
        Optional:    true,
    },
    "first_name": {
        Type:        schema.TypeString,
        Computed:    true,
        Optional:    true,
    },
},
```

Namely, a value for either `id` or `first_name` should be specified but not both (it's a `oneOf` relationship).

In case "id" is specified the code will execute `GET /people/{ID}` otherwise "display_name" must be specified and in this scenario `GET /people` will be called that will return a list of people and the code will run a filter to find the ID of a person that have `response.data.people[i].display_name == {providedDisplayName}`.

Does TF data sources support this kind of configuration (both attributes are computed, optional)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to specify in the schema that the attribute is both `computed` and `optional`, but you would more often see this in a resource schema. In a `resource` and `data` source schema, the `optional` signifies an optional input, and the `computed` signifies its value can be computed during provisioning. It is possible for these to co-exist, as the argument or block could either be input or output. It would not be possible for e.g. `required` to be true and `computed` to be true, since that would be an input and output, and these would conflict.

Additionally, based on the description in your question, you would also want to utilize `ExactlyOneOf`:

```
Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
  "id": {
    Type:         schema.TypeString,
    Optional:     true,
    Computed:     true,
    ExactlyOneOf: []string{"id", "first_name"},
  },
  "first_name": {
    Type:         schema.TypeString,
    Optional:     true,
    Computed:     true,
    ExactlyOneOf: []string{"id", "first_name"},
  },
},
```

Comment: FYI got an error for the provided config: ExactlyOneOf is for configurable attributes,there's nothing to configure on computed-only field

Comment: when I specify a redundant `optional: true` for both fields the error disappears though.

Comment: @AlexKuzminov I have updated answer.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Which parameter would `d.SetId()` take ?

Answer (score 1):

`Optional` and `Computed` together is a good choice for any argument which is serving as a sort of filtering constraint, where the user may either specify it in order to constrain the request *or* omit it in order to learn the value of that attribute as configured in the remote system.

You can see some real examples of this in the AWS provider. For example, [the `aws_vpc` data source uses this pattern for its `cidr_block` argument](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/5c43dcecb5dc39f918decc36f64d483f9e8026dc/internal/service/ec2/vpc_data_source.go#L25-L29), which can be used either as a constraint or as an output:

```
    "cidr_block": {
        Type:     schema.TypeString,
        Optional: true,
        Computed: true,
    },
```

When using this pattern, the provider should distinguish between the argument being set or unset, treating it as an extra constraint on the query if set, or leaving it unconstrained if unset. Then in the latter case, the corresponding value from the query to the remote system would be written into the attribute as part of the result.