# Shall I set both Computed and Optional vs just Optional for a string attribute in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

That's a follow up to [Shall I set an empty string computed string attribute for Terraform resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849664/shall-i-set-an-empty-string-computed-string-attribute-for-terraform-resource/71850659#71850659).

Again, there's a optional request string parameter in my API that I represented in TF as:

```
"foo": {
  Type:        schema.TypeString,
  Optional:    true,
},
```

The gotcha here my server doesn't mutate the string attribute and sends it back.

However `d.Get()` function from SDKv2 returns `""` even if the attribute doesn't exist (e.g., `d.Get("foo")` returns `""` and not null even if the attribute is unset).

I think there's a way to be extremely careful and distinguish between `""` and `null` but it seems like the easier option is to be consistent and use `""` everywhere (it'll help to avoid a lot of ifs as well that makes code more readable).

Is it a reasonable idea? The error I've been getting a lot is when I don't set this attribute in TF configuration but accidentally set this attribute to an empty string and then I got a state diff when running `terraform plan` which is like hey, there's new unexpected `foo=""` attribute in tf state).

On top of that, it seems like it's pretty popular for APIs to return `""` even if `foo` was unset which technically speaking makes any optional attribute optional + computed (null -> "").

Context: I'm using TF SDKv2 for development.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249401/can-an-attribute-be-both-computed-and-optional-in-data-source-in-terraform

Comment: sounds like a yes